# Наклонная штриховка ячейки таблицы средствами css

Tags: html, css

Необходимо выполнить наклонную штриховку ячейки (ячеек) таблицы с помощью css так, чтобы изменение размера ячейки не влияло на возникновение некрасивых стыков между ячейками.

Аналогичная вещь реализована в Excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать так

```css
table {
width:400px
}
.hatching-red {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, red 49.9%, red 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60% ), linear-gradient(45deg, red 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10% );
    background-size: 0.5em 0.5em
}
.hatching-green {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, green 49.9%, green 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60% ), linear-gradient(45deg, green 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10% );
    background-size: 0.5em 0.5em
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
    <td class="hatching-red">1</td>
    <td class="hatching-green">2</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Выглядит хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, при изменение масштаба можно заметить искривление линий и не стыковку между ячейками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить данную проблему? Возможно существует наиболее правильный вариант. Буду рад любому примеру.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать   `background-attachment: fixed;` Это свойство заставляет просчитывать координаты фона не от конкретного элемента, а от страницы в целом.

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.hatching-red {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, red 49.9%, red 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%) 
              fixed,
              linear-gradient(45deg, red 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%) 
              fixed;
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em
}

.hatching-green {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, green 49.9%, green 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%) 
              fixed,
              linear-gradient(45deg, green 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%) 
              fixed;
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hatching-red">1</td>
    <td class="hatching-green">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично работает. Единственное, в Firefox всё  хорошо, а вот Opera искажает линии.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeDEt.png

Comment: Есть такое, но гораздо реже. Попробуйте обойтись одной линией (чуть поменять угол или изменить  `background-size` квадрат на прямоугольник, чтобы вторая добавочная линия стала не нужна)

Comment: Уменьшил size до 0.4. Opera стала отображать корректно, а вот Firefox из прямых стал делать кривые. Ладно. Буду разбираться. Спасибо за помощь!